# unable to create an object of type 'applicationdbcontext'. For the different patterns supported at design time error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

this error keeps popping up when I try to add migration:

> unable to create an object of type 'applicationdbcontext' for the different patterns supported at design time

Startup.cs code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

ApplicationDBContext.cs code:

```
public class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDBContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDBContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core applications are configured using dependency injection. EF Core can be added to this configuration using AddDbContext in the ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs. For example:

```
   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"));
```

You can also initializing it using Simple DbContext initialization with 'new'

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"YourConnectionStringGoesHere");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `var app = builder.Build();` After AddDbContext.

[image]